# Hollyhock with yellowing leaves

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

The leaves on my dwarf hollyhock are steadily turning yellow and falling off.  It's new to the flower bed, gets 6+ hours of full sun/day, and has been sufficiently watered.

Could this be a mineral deficiency?

Comment: how new? what's the history of the flower bed in terms of contents and amendments?

Comment: Picture  please...

Comment: Do you fertilize it? I know hollyhocks in my area (not just on our plants) have a harder time than most flowers (they get holes in their leaves all over, and the leaves turn yellow). I decided to start fertilizing it this year and it's looking somewhat better. I gave it a little wood ash, too.